# Объединение 1000 таблиц csv при определенном условие

Tags: python, pandas

Есть 1000 таблиц csv, которые нужно объединить я воспользовался следующем кодом:

```
    import pandas as pd    
    from pathlib import Path

    data_dir = Path("floder")

    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in data_dir.glob("*.csv")], ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

Но как оказалось в некоторых таблицах отсуствуют названия столбцов(в остальном они идентичны), что привело к тому что обычные значения в понимание человека стали считаться компьютером, как названия столбцов соотвественно эти псевдо столбцы начали прибавляется к нормальным названиям столбцов
В итоги на выходе я получил таблицу не с 12 нормальными столбцами, а 10000+ и пропущенными значениями.
В общем есть ли способ образно говоря не объединять, а склеить.
Если представим что csv файл это листок бумаги, то мы склеиваем нижнею часть первого листка с верхней частью второго листка и так далее.
В этом случае названия столбцов, которые стали значениями можно было бы легко удалить. Или есть другие способы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: ну, например, можно предварительно нормализовать файлы: либо удалить строки с заголовками столбцов из тех файлов, где они есть, либо добавить такие строки в те файлы, где их нет.

Comment: таких файлов много их где то 30% это мартышкин труд)

Comment: `pd.read_csv(f, header=None)` а потом удалить строки с заголовками

Comment: или это делается просто? в рамках 1000 csv файлов?

Comment: @ВладБерд, ну, у вас в руках очень производительная мартышка. сколько миллионов операций она может проделать за секунду! только объясните ей на пальцах, что надо — она всё и сделает.

Comment: дошло попробую)

Comment: тут такое дело.. если я циклом буду перебирать файлы и отключать заголовки, то csv где этих заголовков не было будет убирать первая строка где были значения(

Comment: я не знаю везде ли это, но в моих csv файлах, ни как не указано что заголовок является заголовком, первая строка по определению первой является заголовком(

Comment: Вам же подсказали, что нужно отключить заголовки при чтении csv-файла. и эти заголовки прочтутся как обычные строки датафрейма. вам останется их только найти и удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, мой мозг отказывался понимать что решением моей проблемы может быть 2 слова кода, извините )